# Wrong mode when using PIL.blend with 'F' mode images?

Tags: python-imaging-library

The title says most of it: I'm trying to blend two images with mode `F`, that is 32-bit float pixel values. However, I get an error from `PIL` that says:

```
image has wrong mode
```

However, I have verified that both images are of mode `F` and cannot find any evidence that this shouldn't be possible. Is there some way to make this work, preferably without converting to a new image type?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, that – under the hood – `Image.blend` calls [this](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/d374015504df2c7f0316154deade1bc1fa5075df/src/libImaging/Blend.c) implementation. The very first check there is:

```c
/* Check arguments */
if (!imIn1 || !imIn2 || imIn1->type != IMAGING_TYPE_UINT8 || imIn1->palette ||
    strcmp(imIn1->mode, "1") == 0 || imIn2->palette ||
    strcmp(imIn2->mode, "1") == 0) {
    return ImagingError_ModeError();
}
```

So, although not stated in the documentation, I'd guess, that `Image.blend` is only supported for `uint8` [image modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes).